# stoping infinite loop function using another button

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am writing a function which should return two other functions in it until I decide to stop it. Maybe I even want the function to run 5 hours. I write my code, and it runs perfectly except for one problem: when I click on the starting button, the button stays pressed and I cannot close the infinite loop. I want a way to stop my program without doing key-interrupting or something else. I think a button which can stop my started process would be fine.

Here is my button:

```
self.dugme1 = Button(text="Start ", command=self.start, fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")
self.dugme1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.65)
```

Here are my functions:

```
def greeting(self):
    print("hello")


def byee (self):
    print("bye")


def start(self):
    
    while True:
        self.greeting()
        self.byee()
```

When I click the button these will be run in the terminal infinitely until I stop them using keyboard interrupting. Is there any way to stop it using an elegant way such as a stop button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading on start function. I am sure you'll find more information about this here on over the internet.

Example below:

```
import threading

self.dugme1 = Button(text="Start ",
                     command=lambda: threading.Thread(name='start', target=self.start, daemon=True).start(),
                     fg="black",
                     bg="green",
                     font="bold"
                     )
```

then you can have your start function as:

```
def start(self):
    if self.start_running == False:
        self.start_running = True
        while self.start_running:
            self.greeting()
            self.byee()
```

where `self.start_running` is a variable that is initially set to false at the beginning of your program (or you can set declare it first in start function with a try-except block)

the first if avoids multiple calls to the same button, calling the function more than once.

You can turn "false" the variable `self.start_running` to stop the execution of `start` function.

We want the thread to be `daemon`, so that the function is terminated whenever main terminates.
If you don't want those function to exit abruptly, turn daemon=False, but make sure to signal self.start_running=False, before your program exits.

Comment: Note that function for a button `command` option does not expect an argument, so `command=lambda e: ...` will raise exception.  It should be `command=lambda: ...` instead.

Comment: it gives error , says that AttributeError: 'Uygulama' object has no attribute 'self.start_running'

Comment: thanks acw1668, let me edit the comment. @ulahh you have to define that variable at the start of your program as explained in my comment.

Comment: @mamg2909 i defined but got error , can you show how you defined?

Comment: @ulahh anywhere in the init method. See henry's response where he creates the stop_event variable within de init method.

Comment: @mamg2909 it gives this error : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with threading. The following code demonstrates a start/stop button for an infinitely running process:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target = self.start, args = (self.stop_event,))
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start", command = self.start_cmd)
        self.btn.pack()
    def start_cmd(self):
        self.btn.config(text = "Stop", command = self.stop_cmd)
        self.thread.start()
    def stop_cmd(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.destroy()
    def start(self, stop_event):
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            self.greeting()
            self.byee()
    def greeting(self):
        print("hello")
    def byee(self):
        print("bye")

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.process = threading.Thread(...)` might be confusing to people new to `threading`/`multiprocessing`. It's better to name it `self.thread`

Comment: That's a good point, edited.

Comment: @Henry thanks for your effort , i am beginner in python , so heritance a little confused me. If you have time , can you answer is without using heritance ? Moreover, i import tkinter such that from tkinter import * , to reaach function easily

Comment: @Henry By the way , your method opened new button in another windows , iwant the button appear in main windows , not different one. How can i fix it ?

Comment: @ulahh You use `self` in your question so I assumed you were using a class. What does `self` mean in your question? Also it's better practice to `import tkinter as tk` but if you want to use `from tkinter import *` then just remove the `tk.`.

Comment: @Henry ok , there is no more problem in classses , but the problem is your code open the button in a new windows , but i want it in main window. I guess the second init function give rise to it. Do you have any suggestion to move the button in main window?

Comment: The `self.dugme1` in your code should be replaced with the `self.btn` in my code. If you already have a class you just have to copy the button, threading event, start and stop commands.

Comment: @Henry if i want to apply it for two functions ,should i repeat the same process by changing the variable names ? I tried this way for another button , but something goes wrong. My second button run the first function instead of the second , but when i click on it second time , it return the text whixh is written for second function. Can you please show how this thread to be used when it has more than one function

Comment: @Henry I applied this :  self.stop_eventt = threading.Event()
        self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.start, args=(self.stop_eventt,))
        self.dugme2 = Button(text="click here", command=self.start_cmd2, fg="black", bg="green", font="bold")